# Can C++ console application be user-friendly?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I have C++ console application for GCC with several incoming arguments. Probably, user with advanced knowledge will understand how to build and run the application according to provided description, but how do I make it more user-friendly for an average one?

And is there a way to gather all the files, including some txt ones, that are required in the program, without bothering user?

P.S. It's probably a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer to it, or I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: Are you asking a User to build your program?  Or are you asking Users to execute your program?

Comment: For execution, have you considered a configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following: when you execute the program without parameters, generate a config file (given it doesn't exist). You might go as far as calling $EDITOR . This config file then can have sections, comments, marks on most important values, examples. This is probably the easiest for the average user and you as well. Additionally, you might provide an argument-based interface for sysops and programmers.
Also, I'd suggest some standard format like JSON - or, if it's well-known in the domain, XML.

Answer (score 0):

"Average" users, based on the current population models, probably don't use the console; more technically inclined people use it. So I suppose "average" depends on how you're getting the sample set that defines your "average." Assuming your target audience is at least *slightly* more technically apt...

There are two interpretations I've heard on user friendliness over the years:

1. The dictionary definition of [simple, intuitive, stable, and audience targeted](http://techterms.com/definition/user-friendly).
2. That "user-friendliness" is just what people get used to after having used the application for years, it's not necessarily what works best; it is relative. (This is just what the old salts have told me at least.)

If your application works the way it should and is clearly described in the simplest complete terms, and includes at least one example, it will be user friendly. But you'll never make everyone happy.

I think that *[nmap](https://nmap.org)* is a good example. If you type `nmap --help`, or just `nmap` and hit `enter` a user receives a very good description of how to use `nmap` as well as complete, usable examples.